# Use C# to grab text from an HTML table

Tags: c#, .net, html, html-parsing

I need some advice and possible code examples for parsing an HTML table from a website.  I'm using the webclient class to download the html from an address.  I then need to find the table I want the data from.  So for example if the table id is `<table id="cia_list"`, I want to loop through the `<td>` tags and get just the text inside them.  What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the past I have converted the HTML to XML and then used XSLT to parse the results.  If this is an approach you want to take I would recommend looking at [SGMLReader](http://developer.mindtouch.com/SgmlReader), which will handle the conversion.

People will often attempt to use regex to do what you are talking about.  This is something I typically advise against.  Here is an amusing post that goes over some of the reasons not to do this:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Thank you for the link about not using regex.  I had considered that approach as a viable option.

Comment: Many people do.  Unfortunately, HTML does not cooperate.

Comment: SGMLReader is pretty awesome.  Thank you

Comment: Yeah, it's worked well for me in the past.  The link that @Slaks pointed out looked promising too, so you might check that out also.